# Index out of range in swift

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

I know this error happens when the index is grater than the actual array index. I know there are tons of questions with this same question but I really need to solve this. I've tried a lot of things, like subtracting the index by the array.count, by subtracting 1, 2, etc. The app is a tasks app where you add a task with a category. I'm using a custom class that I created name Task, that has a name, date, and category, the problem is in the category though. Here is the code:

```
var array = [Task]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TaskCell") as? TaskCell {
        if pendingOrComplete.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            if categoriesSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex  == 0 {
                cell.configureCell(tasks[indexPath.row])
            } else if categoriesSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                for task in tasks where task.category == "House" {
                    arr.append(task)
                    cell.configureCell(arr[indexPath.row])
                }
            } else if categoriesSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                for task in tasks where task.category == "School" {
                    arr.append(task)
                    cell.configureCell(arr[indexPath.row])
                }
            }
        } else {
            cell.configureCell(completedTasks[indexPath.row])
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return TaskCell()
    }
}
```

The first segmented control, pendingOrComplete works fine. If the task is pending it will configure the cell with the tasks array, which was declared in this same project and contains all the user's tasks ("var tasks = Task"). Completed tasks is an array of tasks which contains the completed tasks of the array tasks.
Now I started to implement the filtering by category, but I'm getting this strange error "Index out of range" as soon as I tap the firstcategoriesSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex. If I tap the index 0, it works fine, if I tap the index 1, it crashes with a breakpoint and this error.

I've already tried to reload the table view but it throws me into an infinite loop and the table view is blank.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In the code I've returned it, the problem was that I didn't copy the code from the project, so I forgot to put it here. I'm returning it tho

Comment: I've always returned it outside the brackets and it always worked

Comment: I suggest using print statements to show what number of rows you're returning for each section and then the size of each array just before you access it with `indexPath.row`.